# Why my react component is not rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my `react functional component`, I am sending inputs as `props` which are to be displayed and then looping through the inputs to check which inputs are to be displayed according to condition. This is my component :-

```
const TopInputComponent = (props) => {
   const inputs = props.inputs;
   inputs.map((input,index)=>{
        if(input.type == "textInput"){
             return (<Textfield  key={index}
                    onKeyDown={(event)=>{
                        if(event.key == "Enter"){
                            onFilterSelected({'min_price':parseInt(event.target.value)});
                        }
                    }}
                    label={input.placeholder}
                    floatingLabel
                /> )
         }else if(input.type == "selectInput"){
              return  (<div key={index}>
                        <label>{input.placeholder}</label>
                        <select >
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>)
         }

    })  

}
```

I am getting this Error :

> "A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have
>   returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object."

Comment: You are not rendering anything, the map is pretty much disconnected, return your map could do it but then you probably need a parent element still

Answer (score 3):

There are two, three, possibly four problems:

1. You aren't returning anything out of the function, because you haven't *returned* the result of `map`.
2. A React component must return a *single* element or `null`, it can't return an array.
3. Within your `map` callback, you're only returning something if `input.type` is `"textInput"` or `"selectInput"`, not if it's something else. That will leave `undefined` values in your resulting array. If those are the **only** two possible values, change `else if(input.type == "selectInput"){` to just `} else {`. If not, handle the other cases.
4. `floatingLabel` in the `Textfield`'s start tag seems odd, it will be a freestanding boolean attribute.

So you'll probably want to wrap those elements in something, perhaps a `div` (see `***` lines):

```
const TopInputComponent = (props) => {
   const inputs = props.inputs;
   return <div>{inputs.map((input,index)=>{     // ***
        if(input.type == "textInput"){
             return (<Textfield  key={index}
                    onKeyDown={(event)=>{
                        if(event.key == "Enter"){
                            onFilterSelected({'min_price':parseInt(event.target.value)});
                        }
                    }}
                    label={input.placeholder}
                    floatingLabel
                /> )
         } else { // *** Removed: if(input.type == "selectInput"){
              return  (<div key={index}>
                        <label>{input.placeholder}</label>
                        <select >
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>)
         }
    })}</div>;                                  // ***
}
```

Simplified live example:

```js
const MyComponent = props => {
    const {inputs} = props;
    return <div>
        {inputs.map((input, index) => <input key={index} type={input.type} name={input.name} value={input.value || ''} />)}
        </div>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent inputs={[
            {type: "text", name: "one"}, 
            {type: "button", name: "btn", value: "Click me"}
        ]} />,
    document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside `map` you are returning the elements, that elements will group into an `array` by `map` (returns an `array`), You need to `return` the result of `map` also. You are returning an array but react component can't return an array, so wrap the `map` result inside a `div`.

Use this:

```
const TopInputComponent = (props) => {
   const inputs = props.inputs;
   return <div> { inputs.map((input,index)=>{   //added return
   ....
```

One more issue is, inside `map` if you don't return anything by default it will return `undefined`, you are using two condition, may be possible if none of them is `true`, in that case `undefined` will be returned. So always use a `default` case also, use it in this way:

```
return a.map(el => {
    if(/*condition 1*/)
        return //1;
    else if(/*condition 2*/)
        return //2;
    else
        return //3;
})
```

Check this example:

```js
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

function withoutReturn () { a.map(i => i); };

function withReturn () { return a.map(i => i); };

console.log('withoutReturn', withoutReturn());

console.log('withReturn', withReturn())
```

Comment: That's *one* problem. There are two (arguably three). :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for pointing out that, added that in answer :)

Comment: That wasn't the one I meant. I meant the one (returning an array) which will make it not work at all... :-) I don't, at this point, suggest adding it, as there's already an answer highlighting all of these issues.

Comment: added div also he is returning an array.